# How to construe last bracha of Amida these days?

Tags: tefilla, theodicy

In light of the horrors of this past month (the horrific murders and torture and kidnapping perpetrated by Hamas on Oct 7th, 2023), what are the possible ways to understand the last line of the last bracha of the Amida:
Blessed are You L-rd, who blesses His people Israel with peace.

The same question applies to this phrase in Ashrei: 
 He hears their cry and delivers them. 
What of the cries of 100+ hostages and their families and friends (who are also suffering)?

Comment: This question will survive long after the words "this past month" aren't relevant. And the question applies to all the horrors the Jewish people have endured over the many years. Can you make this question more general?

Comment: @magicker72  A more general question might have its merits, but the horrific events of the past month are so unique in our lifetimes that this more specific question is the one I chose to to post.

Comment: In light of the fact that some sick people never recover, how are we to understand the words "He who heals all flesh" in Asher Yotzar?

Comment: When peace comes, He is the one who brought it. We ask for Him to bring it!

Comment: That is the same as asking, "Did Hashem create evil?" Evil has a part to play in Hashem's plan for the world, except we may never see in our lives how that plays out. This is a fundamental Jewish belief, which is why we don't believe in two *reshuyos*.

Comment: I'll have to look up sources later, but the brachah of shalom is a brachah for yeridas hashefa for all of the other things we just finished davening for, by the Kabbalistic interpretation. It's not a brachah for peace, per se.

Comment: Why do bad things happen to good people?

Answer (score 1):

A few possible ideas - sorry I don't have sources: -

1. We would have far less peace if it were not for Hashem's interventions.  Peace doesn't necessarily have to be absolute.
2. It is a request for Him to bless us with peace (I've personally been trying to focus on it as that).
3. Perhaps we didn't merit it at that specific point for some reason.  One thought that I have had is that we know that Hashem treats us *middah k'neged middah*.  Perhaps we haven't exactly treated each other (other Jewish people) with peace - we've quarreled, spoken *lashon hara* about each other, attacked groups with different views to our own and our arguments have been less with the approach of Hillel and Shammai to achieve truth, and more of the approach of Korach.  I think that people have reacted to the tragedy with far more *achdus* than beforehand, but we really need to focus on trying to make sure that we don't slip back into our old habits again.

These are just my own personal ideas, and they aren't mutually exclusive.  All or none of them could be true.

Comment: Concerning "middah k'neged middah", think of the innocent babies involved, living and orphaned.

Comment: +1 for your excellent first 2 points.

Comment: @YehudaW I know, it is hard to understand how they could possibly have deserved that to happen.  I had a long chat with my Rav a few days after it happened because I find it very difficult too.  Unfortunately, that's not a new thing in Jewish history though - I think we just had the illusion that it was history, when we were just fortunate to have had a few decades of relative peace.

Comment: @MosesSupposes What did your Rav say that you found helpful?

Comment: @YehudaW mostly that he was also finding it very difficult!  I think achdus is really important and can help when we feel that we're all going through this together and none of us really understand it.

Comment: If it's a request isn't it strange to be at the end of the amidah which is broken into sections of praise, requests, and thanks?